# CoreData: Can a fetch on a context with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType block the main thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Sorry, this feels like a pretty basic conceptual question, but I am having a hell of a time finding the answer.

Suppose `childContext`is an `NSManagedObjectContext` with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`, and `parentContext` is an `NSManagedObjectContext` with `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`.  And suppose that `childContext.parent == parentContext`.

I know that saving into the `childContext` will eventually have to write to the `parentContext`, temporarily blocking the main thread; is the same true for fetching from the `childContext`?  That is, would the performance of fetching from the child context differ in any way from fetching from the parent context?

Thanks!